# codeception phpbrowser with different URL on dev/staging/live

Tags: codeception

I'm new to Codeception, and trying to reproduce my previous PHPUnit setup.

I have two servers on which I test. They have different URLs for the PphBrowser configuration and I can't figure out how to teach it this.

On my local dev machine, the correct config is:

```
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php/'
```

but on the staging and live machine, it must be:

```
        url: 'http://localhost/'
```

I've not found anything in the documentation that works similar to symfony2's config_dev.yml / config_test.yml files. Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can specify different URL's for each environment.

Please refer the link below for the blog post introducing this feature:

http://codeception.com/11-15-2013/codeception-18-phalcon-environments-dataproviders.html

See the following link for usage and examples:

http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments